# Unable to install a Kibana plugin in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have installed Elasticsearch and Kibana locally on Windows OS.
Now I am trying to install a plugin, using the following command:

```
.\kibana-plugin install .\stagemonitor-kibana-master.zip
```

But I am getting the following error:

[image: Error picture]

What can I do to fix this?